# Issue with resolv.conf - no such file or directory

Tags: resolv.conf

Having a bit of issue restoring my ubuntu box

When I start it I get the following error

Failed to start Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.....dns-clean.service"

When booting into recovery mode > root and attempting to modify the resolv.conf file I get no such file or directory when trying to save changes.

Unable to install any packages or run apt-get update/install -f etc (no internet access)

Appreciate any help.

Cheers

Comment: Two things: 1) did you enable network in recovery mode, 2) did you remount filesystem as `rw`?

Comment: Please show us the full command you use to open the file (resolv.conf).

Comment: No, you don't manually edit /etc/resolv.conf. If you're missing that file all together, it's just a symlink like `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` shows it as `resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. You can recreate it if you have to with a `ln -s` command.

Comment: Yes I tried to, but it quickly reverts me back to main menu and mentioned no directory or file "resolve.conf"

That's what I later figured was to mount the filesystem 

which I did using mount -o remount, rw /

No, I wasn't missing it but I figured its because I hadn't mounted / it was a read-only file and therefore unable to save changes which was to add nameserver address.